# Button click binds to multiple views in custom list view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm using a custom list adapter for a list view. I have defined a button in the list view and the click event works, but the problem is that once the list is scrolled, it binds multiple views with the same button. So on the click of the button, the event associated with each of the associated views is fired.

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Show your code. Without code its impossible to solve :)

Comment: view = (convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HotelCustomListItem, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;

Comment: This is basically what is being done here. I have defined a button in the layout mentioned. as the list is scrolled, new views are created, but the control associated with each view seems to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are misunderstanding how the list works - especially how convertView's are used.

ListViews in Android virtualise the UI - just like ListBoxes do in WP and just like UITableViews do in iOS

What this means is that if the underlying list has 1000 items, but the screen only has room for 10 items, then the list will just create 10 'containers' to show list items, and will use those containers to display just the content that is in view at the time.

The way it does this is through the Adapter - and in particular through the GetView callback - which takes a convertView as one of its parameters.

If you choose to create a new view in your GetView implementation, then you can subscribe to new events in the callback...

If instead you choose to use the convertView in your GetView implementation, then you should not subscribe to new events in the callback - not without unsubscribing the old events first.

e.g. I'm guessing your code does something like this pseudo currently:

```
 public View GetView(int pos, View convertView)
 {
     TextView toShow = convertView as TextView;
     if (toShow == null)
     {
        toShow = new TextView();
     }

     toShow.Text = "Item at position " + i;
     toShow.Click += (s,e) => {
         // do something
     };

     return toShow;
 }
```

The problem with the code is that you will subscribe to Click too often... you'd need to solve it with something like:

```
 public View GetView(int pos, View convertView)
 {
     TextView toShow = convertView as TextView;
     if (toShow == null)
     {
        toShow = new TextView();
        toShow.Click += (s,e) => {
            // do something with the position embedded in toShow.Tag
        };
     }

     toShow.Text = "Item at position " + i;
     toShow.Tag = new WrappedPosition(i);
     return toShow;
 }
```

That's my guess anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Stuart is completely right - problem is that views in ListView are reused (to avoid creating different objects), and as different parts of list are visible, for a new position you could get any view that is not used anymore. So your code should handle this properly.
I would like to add that Garbage Collection for Java objects in monodroid works not good. In my experience, creating lots of objects derived from Java.Lang.Object will crash the application. So:

1. Creating new View for each new row will soon crash the applicaion, so you have to reuse convertView whenever possible.
2. Tag has type Java.Lang.Object, so WrappedPosition should derive from Java object. This means that rather than creating new instance every time, you should reuse same instance.
3. If you move click handler to a separate method, you can just unsubscribe before subscribing, so you will not need any logic "if view is null".

If you find it useful, I may post here example of code that explains how it works. Dodn't post it initially as it's quite big :)